# How can I composite Eevee and Cycles together in one animation sequence?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have a character model that I’d like to render in Cycles only and the rest of the scene in Eevee.

This was suggested to me by someone I had contacted sometime ago.  He said to speed up render times, they’d render their characters in cycles and the rest in Eevee but I cannot remember where I spoke with the guy, otherwise I would ask him how he does it.

I’ve searched the internet but all I’m finding is that it’s not possible to composite Eevee and cycles together.

There must be someway to achieve this!

Does anyone have an ideas how this might be done?

Comment: you can use the Compositor to mix movies made with Eevee and others made with Cycles

Comment: Most likely the *unknown someone* said: render the characters in cycles (as EXR image sequence), Then, in the compositor bring the rendered image sequence and composite them together with the scene rendered in eevee...

Comment: It can be done with separate scenes within the blend file. Andrew Price does the trick in order to render with different compute devices in this tutorial: https://youtu.be/9L8qOq1Shiw?t=3896

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Name your first scene "Cycles" and organize your outliner like this:
[image: Outliner Cycles]

Add a scene and select Linked Copy.
[image: New Scene]
I'll name the new scene "Eevee."

Set up the Eevee scene's outliner like this:
[image: Eevee Outliner]

In the Eevee scene, set up the materials of the objects in the Cycles ***collection*** like so:
[image: Nodes]

Be sure to set *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Clip* (unless otherwise necessary).
[image: Settings]

Back in the Cycles ***scene,*** set up the compositing something like this:
[image: Compositing]

And be sure to enable transparency in the film settings:
[image: Film Transparency]

Whenever you render from the Cycles scene (the one which includes the Eevee render in its compositing nodes), both scenes will render automatically.

[image]

Comment: ..and you've gone to the trouble of testing it with motion blur.. :D